# Retrofit2 + SimpleXML + SOAP request in Kotlin

Tags: soap, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit2, simple-framework

I'm trying to create a service in the Android App that consumes a SOAP API. Sent values and returned values are XML.
Previously i used FormUrlEncoded + JSON in another API and worked, but with XML i'm struggling as the API seems that is not being called (HttpLoggingInterceptor don't show and also the Mockup service don't show any petition).

If i change to FormUrlEncoded my service i can see that the request is done (i checked it with HttpLoggingInterceptor, but if i remove the FormUrlEncoded seems like service is not called never.

My NetModule where is create the retrofir, parser, etc:

```
@Module
class NetModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        val client =
            OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                })
                .build()

        val strategy = AnnotationStrategy()
        val serializer = Persister(strategy)

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create(serializer))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFilesService(retrofit: Retrofit): FilesService =
        retrofit.create(FilesService::class.java)
}
```

My FilesService.kt where the interface is defined is:

```
import com.liderasoluciones.enviotest.data.model.FileSendResponse
import com.liderasoluciones.enviotest.data.model.FileSendEnvelope
import io.reactivex.Flowable
import retrofit2.http.*

interface FilesService {
    @Headers(
        "Content-Type: application/soap+xml",
        "Accept-Charset: utf-8"
    )
    @POST("mockWSSMTSoap")
    fun sendFile(@Body body: FileSendEnvelope): Flowable<FileSendResponse>

}
```

My model for the Body, Request and data is FileSendEnvelope.kt and is:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace;
import org.simpleframework.xml.NamespaceList;

@Root(name = "GetInfoByState", strict = false)
@Namespace(reference = "http://www.webservicetest.net")

class FileSendData {

    @Element(name = "FileName", required = false)
    var name: String? = null

}

@Root(name = "soap12:Body", strict = false)
class FileSendBody {

    @Element(name = "GetInfoByFile", required = false)
    var fileSendData: FileSendData? = null

}

@Root(name = "soap12:Envelope")
@NamespaceList(
    Namespace(prefix = "xsi", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
    Namespace(prefix = "xsd", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"),
    Namespace(prefix = "soap12", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")
)
class FileSendEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "soap12:Body", required = false)
    var body: FileSendBody? = null
}
```

From the RemoteDataSource class is where i call the api:

```
class RemoteFilesDataSource(private val filesService: FilesService,
                            private val genericResponseEntityMapper: GenericResponseEntityMapper):
    FilesDataSource {

    override fun sendFile(userToken: String): Flowable<GenericResponseEntity> {
        var petitionEnvelope = FileSendEnvelope()
        var petitionBody = FileSendBody()
        var petitionData = FileSendData()
        petitionData.name = "test.png"

        petitionBody.fileSendData = petitionData
        petitionEnvelope.body =

        return filesService.sendFile(petitionEnvelope)
            .map { it.result }
            .map { genericResponseEntityMapper.transform(it) }
    }


}
```

At this moment i'm not taking so much care about the XML sent or parse the response, i just "want to check" that the API is called.

I tried to follow this info:
https://github.com/asanchezyu/RetrofitSoapSample
http://geekcalledk.blogspot.com/2014/08/use-simple-xml-with-retrofit-for-making.html

Even are java examples and i'm using Kotlin but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `text/xml` for your `Content-type` in your header? (and try it without the `Accept-Charset` header as well)

```
@Headers(
    "Content-type: text/xml"
)
```